# How do I stop the user from moving the gameobject upwards in the y direction, so the object remains on ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

```
public static void MoveObject(Transform transform, Vector2 deltaPosition, Camera camera = null)
{
    if (transform != null)
    {
        if (deltaPosition.x != 0.0f || deltaPosition.y != 0.0f)
        {
            var rectTransform = transform as RectTransform;

            // If this is RectTransform then modify the anchoredPosition
            if (rectTransform != null)
            {
                rectTransform.anchoredPosition += deltaPosition;
            }
            // If this is Transform then modify the position
            else
            {
                transform.position = MoveObject(transform.position, deltaPosition, camera);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Vector3 MoveObject(Vector3 worldPosition, Vector2 deltaPosition, Camera camera = null)
{
    if (camera == null) camera = Camera.main;

    if (camera != null)
    {
        // Find current screen position of world position
        var screenPosition = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPosition);

        // Modify screen position
        screenPosition += (Vector3)deltaPosition;

        // Write new world position
        worldPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
    }

    return worldPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `==` or `!=` to compare `floats`, because `0.0003F` is different from `0.0002F`. Use `Mathf.Approximately()` instead.

Assuming `y=0` is your ground level:

```
if (!Mathf.Approximately(newPosition.y, 0.0F))
{
  return; //don't move the object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lincoln answer also might work. But you should use al little bit range instead of `==` or `!=` while using **floats**. Like in your example use this

```
if (deltaPosition.x < 0.0f && deltaPosition.x > 0.01f)
```

Because there are very rare chances when floats are exactly equal...